# Type 'ProfilesTableViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource' in Xcode 6 GM seed

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

Today I migrated to Xcode 6 GM seed and now I get the following error:

> Type 'ProfilesTableViewController' does not conform to protocol
>   'UITableViewDataSource'.

I've overrided `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView`. 
In fact everything worked fine till today. I noticed that when I remove `UITableViewDataSource` everything is working fine, and no errors occured. So ..  Is it necessary to use '`UITableViewDataSource`' anymore, or just override the functions from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code compiles fine:

```
class ProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("foo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    return cell
}
}
```

So, you can definitely subclass `UITableViewController` and define its `UITableViewDataSource` protocol implementation.

Take notice that I am using the `override` keyword and also that I am not using auto-unwrapped arguments -- i.e., not like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
```

which was correct in previous Xcode 6 betas.

Comment: The truth is that we both are right ... Because what you gave me as an example it is from the SDK ... But i needed a small modification of the code in sdk in irder to use conditional assiging ... So your code works and my code in my answer works too ... :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're not implementing all the [required methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), based on the error, at least.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Because of the `Xcode 6 beta` syntax:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!){
```

We had to check the unwrapped tableView. So I used:

```
        if let tblView = tableView {
            //code
        }
```

and

```
    if let theIndexPath = indexPath {
            //code
    }
```

So ... in order not to change my entire project, I overrided the functions like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?){
```

and everything worked fine, except that with my changes the ProfileTableViewController doesn't conform `UITableViewDataSource`, and I've had to remove the data source from the class definition.

Comment: I am afraid to say that this is incorrect. Check my answer, please.